# UPS shipping is only returning three methods

Tags: shipping, ups

I am using UPS for shipping method and set the shipping origin to colorado USA, products have set their weight but i am getting only three shipping methods to ship I am on CE 1.7.0 i have checked with another installation with same version and that working great, so i have copied the shipping module to my live site and this is super unfortunate that tihs is not working.

United Parcel Service

```
    Next Day Air Saver $99.97
    Next Day Air $107.35
    Next Day Air Early AM $140.65
```

Note : I have set up all the conditons to a test site with same CE 1.7.0 version there they are working fine but for live site only three rates are coming.

Any idea for this.

Thnaks

Comment: Before you started this process, what was selected in System Config -> Shipping Methods -> UPS -> Allowed Ship Methods?

Comment: We were testing for second day air a.m. as it were not populating and some general methods was selected ground and next day air.. for canada and US only.

Answer (score 2):

Ok folks i have solved the problem

I have searched for all ups setting in `core_config_data` table and delete all the entries

the query was `select * from core_config_data where path like '%ups%'` deleted all the records and re-save the settings this solved the problem.

Hope this could help some one.

Comment: Don't edit the database directly. Ever.

Comment: @sonassi Hmm i know i took this way when i had 5 hrs of a day pulling my hairs out of my head... any other standard approach i can do this. Thanks

Comment: The trouble is that you're probably in this position because you've manually edited the DB in the past. Its a continuous circle. Thankfully there is no keys to be broken in `core_config_data` - but we don't advocate editing the DB under any circumstance. Its a road to ruin ...

Comment: @sonassi Hmm.. this could be the case but honestly i haven't edit the DB ever.

Comment: @sonassi I hate to disagree with you, but there is no harm done by altering the config tables in this way. And for what it's worth, Magento has put out bulitins which walk one through doing things directly with the database such as clearing out test order data. It's a matter of knowing what not to touch apart from the resource model layer, and this is not one of them.

Comment: @davidalger - I agree with you. But my (sweeping) comment was pointed at those not "in the know". More often than not, there isn't a use case for editing the DB directly - and unless the person doing it knows exactly what they are doing (the OP in this case didn't); then there is much more room for harm than good. ***Files are repairable - databases are not***. Once you've screwed up a foreign key relationship; its not easily seen, and it *will* cause lasting effects.

Comment: @sonassi - That being clarified, I will agree with you! :)